# MySql: rebuilding indexes after collation change

Tags: mysql, collation

A while ago I have changed collation on some tables from utf8_swedish_ci to utf8_general_ci - before I had a mix of both. Most of the tables have additional indexes set. Should I drop & rebuild all the indexes because of the change?

I wonder about it because tables with different collations won't use indexes on joins and slows down queries a bit, and I'm not sure what happens to the index after collation is changed.

Comment: Flagged to move to [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).